# INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria returns N/A result, but match criteria look correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to reshape a dataset in excel from long to wide using the index-match combination, but my match index formula returns NA's

I checked to see if the match criteria we're correctly specified using a combination of sumproducts and countifs. This gave me the expected result of 1.

I feel like I am making some dumb syntax error in the index-match code and would love a little guidance.

```
=INDEX(D_DATABASE!$AA$4:$BBT$260,
         MATCH(1,(AA$1=D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260)*
                 ($U4=D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260)*
                 (AA$3=D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3),0))


 =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(AA$1,D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260,U4,
                       D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260,AA$3,
                       D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3))
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the formula with the Formula Evaluate tool? You may want to use a smaller data set to see how the arrays are combined.

Comment: Are you entering the first one as an array formula?  (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: Your row-wise equality check might need to be wrapped in TRANSPOSE - `MATCH(1,(AA$1=D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260)*
                 ($U4=D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260)*
                 TRANSPOSE((AA$3=D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3)),0)`

Comment: ...though your arrays are not the same size (last one is much larger) so it's not clear what you're trying to discover here

Comment: @TimWilliams , your last two comments hit the nail on the head. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the TRANSPOSE function didn't help. The first two matches are for year and firm  and should identify the row I want. I want the the third match to look across the array to identify the column which is the variable I want to pull.

Is this even possible for me to do or can index match only work if all the ranges are the same size and orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
=INDEX(D_DATABASE!$AA$4:$BBT$260,
              MATCH(1,(AA$1=D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260)*
                      ($U4=D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260)*
                      (AA$3=D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3),0))
```

...your last comparison is row-oriented vs columns for the other two, so you could try wrapping that in TRANSPOSE:

```
=INDEX(D_DATABASE!$AA$4:$BBT$260,
              MATCH(1,(AA$1=D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260)*
                      ($U4=D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260)*
                      TRANSPOSE((AA$3=D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3)),0))
```

However, that last comparison also uses a much larger range than the previous two, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this.

**EDIT after more info**: you need to separate out that last row-wise search into its own MATCH

```
=INDEX(D_DATABASE!$AA$4:$BBT$260,
       MATCH(1,(AA$1=D_DATABASE!$N$4:$N$260)*($U4=D_DATABASE!$U$4:$U$260),0),
       MATCH(AA$3,D_DATABASE!$AA$3:$BBT$3,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the TRANSPOSE function didn't help. The first two matches are for year and firm  and should identify the row I want. I want the the third match to look across the array to identify the column which is the variable I want to pull.

Is this even possible for me to do or can index match only work if all the ranges are the same size and orientation?

Comment: Here are examples of my database
https://ibb.co/fqjKphx  This is what my dataset looks like
https://ibb.co/SJpfxkh This is how I want to transpose it.

Comment: Thank you Tim! You saved me many hours of hitting my head against a wall.